# Training Machine Learning in Production

Tags: machine-learning

Is there a way to train your machine learning model in the cloud? Or does it really have to be batch training? i.e. (Pull some data on SQL, then feed that to the model)

What i was thinking is implementing my own model from scratch, use Stochastic Gradient Descent to update the parameters for every row from the database.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a field of [online machine learning](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Online_machine_learning) where incremental updates can be made to a model, including a variation of stochastic gradient descent called [incremental stochastic gradient descent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Online_machine_learning#Stochastic_gradient_descent).

Generally, several rows of data are batched together to perform an update to the parameters. Training on a single row of data at a time can lead to unstable updates.